# Плавное появление картинки

Tags: java, android, xml

Всем добрый день, нужна небольшая помощь.

Хочу реализовать анимацию, чтобы при нажатии на button вызывался метод my(), который в свою очередь обеспечивал бы медленное появление картинки. Но т.к. я в этом деле новичок, хочу сделать сначала картинку невидимой, а потом при нажатии на button видимой, но не получается.

Подскажите, что следует изменить?

И если не трудно, буду очень благодарен, если посоветуете хорошую литературу касательно разработки в Android Studio.

Разметка `mImageView`.

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/sea"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:alpha="0"/>
```

Метод `my`.

```
public void my(View view){
    mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    mFadeInAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fadein);
    mImageView.startAnimation(mFadeInAnimation);
}
```

Comment: [посмотрите это](http://www.journaldev.com/9481/android-animation-example)

Comment: используемая IDE никак не влияет на решение проблемы. IDE указывается в тегах, только если проблемы в самой IDE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поставьте

```
android:visibility="invisible"
```

Тем самым изначально она будет невидимой

Искать `view` нужно только один раз, в `onCreate`, уберите туда строчку с `findViewById`. Далее

```
public void my() {
    ViewCompat.animate(mImageView).withStartAction(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                mImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
    })
    .alpha(1f)
    .setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator())
    .setDuration(250)
    .start();
```

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

```
public void my(View view){
    mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    mImageView.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(500);
}
```

Comment: Плохо. Разве вы не знаете что искать `view` нужно только один раз, в `onCreate`? К тому же проблема не в этом, у автора в xml нет `android:visibility="invisible"`

Comment: @Flippy, плохо то что вы невнимательны и не учли, что ТС сам пишет о том что он новичок. И рассказывать ему в вопросе об анимации о том как нужно находить View может быть излишне. Вы и сами должны были видеть множество вопросов, где убирание первой строки привело бы к тому, что ТС вместо работающего способа вынужден был бы часами разбираться почему же у него NPE возникает вместо анимации. Вы же не ожидали, что вместо ответа об анимации в в ответе была бы лекция о ViewBinding?